# Query com resultado aleatório

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho a query abaixo, usada em uma rotina interna, para distribuição de itens para separação em coletores de dados:

```
Select distinct IP, USUARIO, DATA
from
PCN_ROMANEIO_ACESSO    PRA
Where pra.STATUS = 'OK'
AND trunc(pra.DATA) = trunc(sysdate)
AND PRA.DATA_SAIDA IS NULL
AND IP <> '192.168.204.1'
AND NIVEL = 'S'
order by 3
```

Na situação acima, é sempre ordenado pela data/hora de login no sistema. Com isso o coletor sempre irá receber itens diferentes para separação do dia anterior. Mas o que ocorre é que muitas vezes o usuário entra no sistema na entrada do turno e não sai mais até o fim, ai no momento da distribuição ele acaba sempre recebendo itens da mesma familia, o que para eles é ruim.

Nesse caso, existe algum comando do tipo `SORT` onde a cada execução do select acima ele ordenasse de forma aleatória?

UPDATE: Estou usando Oracle SQL

Comment: Qual banco você está usando?

Comment: A função ORDER BY RAND() também funciona no DB2/400

Comment: Sample ou random ... https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/IRWUG/ch12s04s04s10.html ...  https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/sql/188/select-random-rows.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### SQL Server

Se for SQL Server, então você pode usar o `NewId(`) no `Order By`.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT IP,
    USUARIO,
    DATA
FROM
    PCN_ROMANEIO_ACESSO PRA
WHERE
    pra. STATUS = 'OK'
AND trunc (pra. DATA) = trunc (sysdate)
AND PRA.DATA_SAIDA IS NULL
AND IP <> '192.168.204.1'
AND NIVEL = 'S'
ORDER BY
    NEWID()
```

### Oracle

Se for Oracle, `DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM()`

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        IP,
        USUARIO,
        DATA
    FROM
        PCN_ROMANEIO_ACESSO PRA
    WHERE
        pra. STATUS = 'OK'
    AND trunc (pra. DATA) = trunc (sysdate)
    AND PRA.DATA_SAIDA IS NULL
    AND IP <> '192.168.204.1'
    AND NIVEL = 'S'
    ORDER BY
        DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM()
)
```

### PostGreSQL

Se for PostGreSQL, `RANDOM()`.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT IP,
    USUARIO,
    DATA
FROM
    PCN_ROMANEIO_ACESSO PRA
WHERE
    pra. STATUS = 'OK'
AND trunc (pra. DATA) = trunc (sysdate)
AND PRA.DATA_SAIDA IS NULL
AND IP <> '192.168.204.1'
AND NIVEL = 'S'
ORDER BY
    RANDOM()
```

### MySql

Se for MySql, `RAND()`.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT IP,
    USUARIO,
    DATA
FROM
    PCN_ROMANEIO_ACESSO PRA
WHERE
    pra. STATUS = 'OK'
AND trunc (pra. DATA) = trunc (sysdate)
AND PRA.DATA_SAIDA IS NULL
AND IP <> '192.168.204.1'
AND NIVEL = 'S'
ORDER BY
    RAND()
```

Comment: Estou usando Oracle SQL...

Comment: Isso ai, deu certo. Obrigado!